# Create React App cannot find declared module

Tags: typescript, create-react-app, typescript-typings, tsconfig, react-tsx

I have a project create with CRA typescript.

at the root of project there exists `tsconfig.json` and a folder called `types`. at the types folder I have created a `modulename.d.ts` file for a module that does not have default typings at node_modules and also there is nothing for it at `@types\module-name`.

but I get the error at compile time.

> Type error: Could not find a declaration file for module 'thename'. '/*/node_modules/thename/dist/entry.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.

why the compiler does not find the type declaration at types folder?

```
// .d.ts
declare module 'foo-react' {
    import * as React from 'react';
    // ...
}
```

this is the `tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": { "*": ["types/*"] },
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "plugins": [{ "name": "typescript-tslint-plugin" }],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "preserve"
  },
  "include": ["src"]
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So it turned out that

1. I renamed the custom types folder to `@types`
2. the path to `@types` folder (my customized one at the root of the project) should be added to `types` attribute and not the `paths` attribute.  `"types":["./@types"]`
3. In the `@types` folder having a structure like `@types/<module_name>/index.d.ts` or `@types/moduleName.d.ts`. Now the file can declare that module as `any` or declare all types in detail.

definition for types compiler option in [Typescript handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html)

> --types   string[]        List of names of type definitions to include. See [@types, —typeRoots and —types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#types) for more details.